# How to make it so that when you press a png icon it takes u to the home which is '/' in NavLink without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

So this is my code :

```
                   <div key="1" className="menu-item">
                    <NavLink to="/">

                        <span className="icon-home3" />&nbsp; Home
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
```

The Home button works fine without reloading the page but the png icon makes the page reload everytime. Why is that and how do I fix this?

Here is the image component:

```
const Logo = () => {
return (
    <center style={{ marginTop: '4%' }}>
        <a
            href="/"
            className="logo"
            title="Home" >
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,..." alt="Logo" />
        </a>
    </center>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to replace `a` element to `NavLink` component. `NavLink` does the magic - redirects without refreshing.

```
const Logo = () => {
  return (
    <center style={{ marginTop: '4%' }}>
        <NavLink to="/"
            className="logo"
            title="Home" >
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,...." alt="Logo" />
        </NavLink>
    </center> 
  );
}
```